# Trigger event every 2 minutes when typing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to trigger an event for every 2 minutes when you are typing, in any `input` or `textarea`.

If you then stops typing, the event will happen one more time, in the remaining time of the 2 minutes. *(Hope you understand)*

It is very much the same function as the one **WordPress** are using, when a draft is autosaved once per minute.

I am no Wordpress expert, so I can't find the function they are using in their scripts.

This is what I've got so far:

```
    $("input, textarea").keyup(function () {
    var minutes = 2;
    var time = minutes * 60000;
    setInterval(function () {
        // Do event here
    }, time);
});
```

It doesn't work that well. If you are typing many characters the event will be triggered multiple times right after each others. Also the event is triggered even if you are clicking on Ctrl, the arrow keys..... which is not intended.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TheYaXxE/AgNGJ/1/)

And I can't seem to find a good way to detect, when a user has stopped typing.

I've found this code, but I don't know how to use it, along with the other code I'm using:

```
//setup before functions
var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 5000;  //time in ms, 5 second for example

//on keyup, start the countdown
$('#myInput').keyup(function(){
    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
});

//on keydown, clear the countdown 
$('#myInput').keydown(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
});

//user is "finished typing," do something
function doneTyping () {
    //do something
}
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `setInterval` but `setTimout` and spawn a new one only after the first has been run..

```
var saveTimer = null,
    minutes = 2,
    time = minutes*60000;

$("input, textarea").keyup(function () {
    if (!saveTimer){
        saveTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            alert("Hello");
            saveTimer = null;
        }, time);
    }
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/h9pe3/

Comment: This works pretty good :). The only thing now, is only to do the event, if the text are changed. Right now if you are clicking at the arrow keys or the any other keys, the event will be triggered.

Comment: @TheYaXxE you could use `input` event instead of `keyup` but that would only work on modern browsers.. `$('input,textarea').bind('input', function(){...});` For more see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMozilla_event_reference%2Finput

Answer (score 0):

You could set a boolean to check for new user input like [I did in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AgNGJ/2/)

```
var hasTyped = false;

$("input, textarea").keyup(function () {
    hasTyped = true;


});
var minutes = 0.1;
var time = minutes*60000;
setInterval(function() {
    if(hasTyped){     
        alert("Hello");
        hasTyped = false;
    }
}, time);
```

The other code you posted works a bit different: instead of running every 2 minutes, it will run 5 seconds after you stopped typing. For autosave this would be a good solution as well, depending on your preference.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/RWBYH/2/

```
//setup before functions
var typingTimer = null;                //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 2000;  //time in ms, 2 second for example

//on keyup, start the countdown
$('input').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer); // clearing timer
    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
});

//on keydown, clear the countdown 
$('input').keydown(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
});

//user is "finished typing," do something
function doneTyping() {
    alert("Saving draft");
}
```

The sample code provided works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/RWBYH/1/

```
//setup before functions
var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 5000;  //time in ms, 5 second for example

//on keyup, start the countdown
$('input, textarea').keyup(function(){
    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
});

//on keydown, clear the countdown 
$('input, textarea').keydown(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
});

//user is "finished typing," do something
function doneTyping () {
    alert("Saving draft");
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is, that if your a typing many characters right after each others, the alert will show multiple times, right after each others

Comment: Oh true, adding a ```clearTimeout``` to every keyup event fixes it. edited my answer with correct fiddle attached. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need something called time based event [throttling](http://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls/).

Demo on http://jsfiddle.net/Gobie/LUv2u/

```
// taken from Remy Sharp's page
function throttle(fn, threshhold, scope) {
  threshhold || (threshhold = 250);
  var last,
      deferTimer;
  return function () {
    var context = scope || this;

    var now = +new Date,
        args = arguments;
    if (last && now < last + threshhold) {
      // hold on to it
      clearTimeout(deferTimer);
      deferTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        last = now;
        fn.apply(context, args);
      }, threshhold);
    } else {
      last = now;
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }
  };
}

// actual code
var interval = 2 * 60 * 1000; // 2min
$("input, textarea").keyup(throttle(function () {
   console.log(new Date);
}, interval));
```

Answer (score 0):

First we want to be able to tell if the user is typing or he as stopped. We can do that by checking every couple of seconds when the last key stroke was. If it's been, let's say 30sec. since the last one we can assume that he's not typing. The second interval will autosave every two minutes and if the user is not typing anymore it will clear itself.

```
var isTyping = false;
var lastKeystroke = null;
var autosaveInterval = null;
$('#myInput').keyup(function() {
   lastKeystroke = Date.now();
   if (autosaveInterval == null) {
     startAutosaveInterval();
   }
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (Date.now() - lastKeystroke > 30000) { // 30 sec. since last key stroke
    isTyping = false;
  } else {
    isTyping = true;
  }
}, 2000);

function startAutosaveInterval() {
  autosaveInterval = setInterval(function() {
    // do whatever
    if (!isTyping) {
      clearInterval(autosaveInterval);
      autosaveInterval = null;
    }
  }, 2 * 60 * 1000); // every two minutes
}
```

I have not tested this code. but you should be able to take it from here.